# Magento2 InstallSchema.php does not create the table specified

Tags: magento2, database, table

I have an InstallSchema.php that just does not create the necessary table in the database. The code of the schema is as fallows :

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\Helpdesk\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
*   @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface    $setup, 
                            ModuleContextInterface  $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $table = $installer->getConnection()
                            ->newTable($installer->getTable('myvendor_helpdesk_ticket'))
                            ->addColumn(
                                    'ticket_id',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                                    null,
                                    ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                                    'Ticket Id'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                    'customer_id',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                                    null,
                                    ['unsigned' =>  true],
                                    'Customer Id'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                    'title',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    null,
                                    ['nullable' =>  false],
                                    'Title'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                    'severity',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                                    null,
                                    ['nullable' =>  false],
                                    'Severity'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                    'created_at',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                                    null,
                                    ['nullable' =>  false],
                                    'Created At'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                    'status',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                                    null,
                                    ['nullable' =>  false],
                                    'Status'
                            )
                            ->addIndex(
                                    $installer->getIdxName('myvendor_helpdesk_ticket',  ['customer_id']),
                                    ['customer_id']
                            )
                            ->addForeignKey(
                                    $installer->getFkName('myvendor_helpdesk_ticket', 'customer_id', 'customer_entity', 'entity_id'),
                                    'customer_id',
                                    $installer->getTable('customer_entity'),
                                    'entity_id',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_SET_NULL
                            )
                            ->setComment('myvendor  Helpdesk Ticket');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I've run the fallowing commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
```

No errors were given, yet, when i get to my page I receive the fallowing error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.myvendor_helpdesk_ticket' doesn't exist
```

Please, help.

Comment: Did you define ‘myvendor_helpdesk_ticket’ anywhere? it may just be failing on the installer->getTable().

Comment: what do u mean by define ? can you please provide a small example

Comment: I did create a ResourceModel, where I do app/code/MyVendor/Helpdesk/Model/ResourceModel/Ticket.php: $this->_init('myvendor_helpdesk_ticket', 'ticket_id'); If that is defining it... Everywhere else where I have the 'myvendor_helpdesk_ticket' string is in the code I've posted

Comment: i replaced "->newTable($installer->getTable('myvendor_helpdesk_ticket'))" with "->newTable('myvendor_helpdesk_ticket')" ... still nothing

Comment: but are you sure your install script is called?

Comment: no, how can I make sure about that ? I do also think that it is not called, no other reason in my mind for not creating it, but what do I do ?

Comment: just put an echo in there, or write in a file from the `install` method and see if you get a result

Comment: i put die('DDDD'); before the class declaration, nothing happened, no change

Comment: try deleting from the table `setup_module` the record with `module = 'MyVendor_Helpdesk'`

Comment: That solved it, can u create it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct solution. I delete manually with a query, then i ran the setup:upgrade and setup:db-schema:upgrade and it worked! Thank you man!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The installer won't run again if it was already executed.
Removing the record from `setup_module` with module = 'MyVendor_Helpdesk' should make it run again.

Comment: Awesome Marius it is worked for me.

Comment: And then `php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade` worked for me

Comment: Thanks @Marius it works for me.

Comment: You should also ensure the namespace is correct in Setup/InstallSchema.php

Comment: Thanks @Marius, It worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

please try the following code.

```
delete from setup_module where  module ='module_name';
sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo bin/magento cache:clean
```

if you get any permissions errors on var folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Something i often do is drop the table if exists on InstallSchema.php:

```
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){
    $setup->startSetup();
    // Drop table for development purpose
    $setup->getConnection()->dropTable($setup->getTable('my_custom_table')); ...
```

After this do:

1. Access your DB
2. Run the following command: **DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE  module ='module_name';**
3. Exit your DB
4. In your Magento Root Folder execute: **php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade**
5. Check if everything is ok in your custom table.

Answer (score 0):

just go to magento database and first delete the row from the setup_module table matching the name of your module that it should then run the InstallSchema  again -  #php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade